# Order a string by considering it as an integer

Tags: c#, linq

Sorry I'm asking too many questions in a row.

I have a list of strings like this:

"firstnumber-lastnumber"

I want to sort it by first number and then by last number

for example if I have:

```
"2-43"
"1-11"
"1-9"
```

after the sorting it should be like this:

```
"1-9"
"1-11"
"2-43"
```

I used this LINQ query:

```
numbers.OrderBy(s => s.Split('-')[0]).ThenBy(s => s.Split('-')[1]);
```

but this query order them by string logic and not by int logic.

so if I have 2 and 11 I want 2 to come before 11

(the ordering by string logic order the 11 before 2 since it starts with '1')

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Any chance you could update the database to use two columns of type int?  Seems strange to store numbers as string if you need to do numeric comparisons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `int.Parse(str)` to convert `str` to a number.

```
numbers.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Split('-')[0])).ThenBy(s => int.Parse(s.Split('-')[1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using vcepa's `StringLogicalComparer` class.  It uses a similar ordering, and he's already figured out all the gotchas.

**Numeric String Sort in C#** 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11016/Numeric-String-Sort-in-C